# UISegmentedControl changes tint color after dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have `UISegmentedControl` on my controller. Which tint color works fine when I am opening it for the first time. But on the back button pressed I will dismiss the controller. And when reopen the same controller, the tint color of `UISegmentedControl` disappear. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: When open first time]

[image: When reopen after dismissing]

```
headerSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentItemsArray];
headerSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
headerSegment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
headerSegment.layer.borderWidth = 0;
headerSegment.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[headerSegment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [ApplicationColors skyBlueColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [ApplicationColors segmentNormalColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

headerSegment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
headerSegment.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerSegment.backgroundColor = [ApplicationColors lightGrayBackgroundColor ];
headerSegment.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[headerSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[contentHolderView addSubview:headerSegment];
```

Comment: you have set tint color programmatically ?

Comment: Please provide some code what you have done.

Comment: show me code for segmentcontrol and backbutton and viewDidLoad() code

Comment: @NiravKotecha - Yes i set it by programmatically.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed - i added my code in question. Please check.

Comment: `[UISegmentedControl appearance]` may be responsible for this, Just remove those lines and check it with default colors.

Comment: @Krunal - But i need it. because it's my customized Segment Control. For normal state text color should be gray and for selected it should be blue. that's why i set its appearance.

Comment: If this code in viewDidLoad then move this code to viewWillAppear and then try.

Comment: set yes this property --> `headerSegment.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;`

Comment: @NiravKotecha - I am setting constraints programmatically. So if i set is as YES, it constraints will get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code, (it works for me)

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UISegmentedControl * headerSegment;    
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addsegmentcontrol];
}


-(void)addsegmentcontrol{


    headerSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"]];
    headerSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    headerSegment.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
    headerSegment.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    headerSegment.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                           forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [headerSegment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [headerSegment setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [headerSegment setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    headerSegment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    headerSegment.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerSegment.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    headerSegment.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    //[headerSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:headerSegment];
     headerSegment.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 44);
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Here is sample result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You... Its working now. Instead of setting UISegmentedControl appearance i have to set directly on headerSegment which is created.